# Shell Scripting : syntax error near unexpected token `while'

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am executing the script in Linux and very new to it:-

```
 #!/bin/bash 
 for FILENAME   in /u01/oracle/domains/custom.log  

 while :

   do  
    FILESIZE=$(stat -c%s "$FILENAME")

        if [[ $FILESIZE > 1000000 ]] ;then
        echo "$FILENAME is too large = $FILESIZE bytes."
        > $FILENAME
        fi
     sleep 2m
    done    
  exit 0
```

I am getting error as:

```
./ScriptCustom.sh: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `while'
./ScriptCustom.sh: line 4:  `while :'
```

Comment: The basic syntax of `for` loops in `sh` is `for X; do Y; done`. You're missing some parts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is on the `for` statement, it is not complete. The syntax of the `for` statement is:

`for` *name [* `in` *word ]* `; do` *list* `; done`

`for`, `in`, `do`, `done` and the semicolon (`;`) are keywords, *name*, *word* and *list* are language concepts and the square brackets (`[` and `]`) are notation helpers that tell the fragment they wrap is optional. The brackets themselves are not part of the statement, they must not appear no matter if the fragment they wrap is included or not.

Back to your code, it should be along the lines of:

```
for FILENAME in /u01/oracle/domains/custom.log; do
   while :
   do
       # ...
   done    # end while
done       # end for
```

However, if the *list* contains only one item (`/u01/oracle/domains/custom.log`) you don't even need the `for` statement. You can simply assign the value to the variable instead of using a `for` block:

```
FILENAME=/u01/oracle/domains/custom.log  
while :
do
    # ...
done    # end while
```

Comment: Thanks axia...it did worked for me..Thanks and lot guys

Answer (score 0):

while needs a condition to test.

For an infinite loop, do:

```
while [ 1 ]
do
    some commands
done
```

Comment: It doesn't need a *condition*, it needs something which yields a *status code*, and continues looping as long the status code is zero. In this case, the argument to while is the *colon-command' (`:`), which always returns a zero-status, and so the loop runs forever.